# nodejs upload image to bucket and give it 'shared publicity' property

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, buckets

Got some question related to uploading image and sharing it.
I found related question with answer, but it does now work. Google cloud responds with this error

[NodeJS gcloud - Upload to google storage with public-read property/custom cache-expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27248518/nodejs-gcloud-upload-to-google-storage-with-public-read-property-custom-cache)

```
   { [Error: Required]
     errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'required', message:    'Required' } ],
   code: 400,
  message: 'Required',
   response: undefined }
```

Ideally i want to upload a file, and then access it though public domain. I don't want to have any streaming solutions, as in like opening file through api.

```
    // bucket is defined, uploading is fine
    var file = bucket.file(id);
    stream.pipe(file.createWriteStream());

    //Giving permissions
    bucket.acl.default.add({
        scope: "allUsers",
        role: gcloud.storage.acl.READER_ROLE
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
       // i am getting an error there
    })
```

Thanks!

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: The question is why am i getting the error. The error response is very vague

Comment: The console output is not complete. As you can see, [Error: Required] had been truncated. Instead of console.log, try `console.log(require('util').inspect(err, {depth: null}))`